# what is the final velocity of the combined mass

Tags: measure-theory

A 0.25 arrow with a velocity of 12 m/s west strikes and pierces the center of a movable 6.8 kg target.

What is the final velocity of the combined mass?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Combine the mass of the arrow and target. $P = mv$.

$v=\frac{m_1v_1+m_2v_2}{m_1+m_2}$